# Pandas: What is dtype = <U64, and How Do I Convert it to String?

Tags: pandas, numpy, types

I have a table, and one column is loaded as np.str from csv. But the dtype says this weird U64 (I guess meaning, unsigned int 64 bit?) and converting with astype doesn't work.

```
stringIDs = extractedBatch.ID.astype(np.str)
```

After astype the dtype says 'object'

Comment: 'U64' is a 64 character unicode.  That's a normal string in Py3 `numpy`.  Why do you think you need to convert it?  `astype(np.str)` is the same as `astype(object)`.  That conversion makes a object dtype array containing Python strings.

Comment: When I add the value to a 'real' string I get: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U64') dtype('<U64') dtype('<U64')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [313]: arr = np.array(['one','twenty'])                                                               
In [314]: arr                                                                                            
Out[314]: array(['one', 'twenty'], dtype='<U6')
In [315]: arr.astype(object)                                                                             
Out[315]: array(['one', 'twenty'], dtype=object)
```

`np.char` applies string methods to elements of a string dtype array:

```
In [316]: np.char.add(arr, ' foo')                                                                       
Out[316]: array(['one foo', 'twenty foo'], dtype='<U10')
```

`add` is not defined for numpy string dtypes:

```
In [317]: np.add(arr, ' foo')                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-317-eff87c160b77> in <module>
----> 1 np.add(arr, ' foo')

TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U6') dtype('<U6') dtype('<U6')
```

This use of `np.add` turns the 'foo' string into an array before trying to use it.  It's trying to add a 'U6' string to a 'U6' string.

`np.add` when applied to an object dtype array, delegates the action to the corresponding method of the elements.  Since `add` is defined for Python strings, it works:

```
In [318]: np.add(arr.astype(object), ' foo')                                                             
Out[318]: array(['one foo', 'twenty foo'], dtype=object)
```

This pattern applies to all the numpy `ufunc`.  They are defined for specific `dtypes`.  If given `object` dtypes, they delegate - which may or may not work  depending on the methods of the elements.

Both the `object` and `np.char` approaches do the equivalent of a list comprehension, and at about the same speed:

```
In [324]: [i+' foo' for i in arr]                                                                        
Out[324]: ['one foo', 'twenty foo']
```

===

Example with string replication *

```
In [319]: arr*2                                                                                          
TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U6') dtype('<U6') dtype('<U6')

In [320]: arr.astype(object)*2                                                                           
Out[320]: array(['oneone', 'twentytwenty'], dtype=object)

In [322]: np.char.multiply(arr,2)                                                                        
Out[322]: array(['oneone', 'twentytwenty'], dtype='<U12')
```

Comment: How do I convert the output of np.char.add to the np.str... The final type needs to be np.str

Comment: `arr[0]' is a subclass of `str`, so `arr[0] + ' foo'` works.  `arr.tolist()`.  `arr.tolist()` produces a list of `str` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas doesn't use a str dtype, it uses object (even if the underlying values are str):

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(['a'], dtype='U64')

In [12]: type(s[0])
Out[12]: str
```

Comment: When I add the objects to a string I get: ValueError: operation parameter must be str

Comment: @user1581390 oh,  I misread it's unicode 64 (i.e. already string).